# Android release memory from drawable

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

So I'm using a service and at some point I need to run this:

```
Bitmap wallpaperBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) WallpaperManager
                                .getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```

Then set this bitmap as background to a view that I keep it in my service using

```
View.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(res, wallpaperBitmap));
```

Thing is that as soon as I get the drawable from `WallpaperManager` my service's RAM usage jumps up because the `wallpaperBitmap` is kept in memory. Or probably the drawable returned by the `WallpaperManager` is the one kept in memory (I'm not exactly sure). How can I release the memory from this background?

To be noted: I do change the background of the view to a color after some time and the bitmap no longer shows as the background but the RAM is never freed. Also I tried `wallpaperBitmap.recycle()` but the memory is still not cleared. How do I release that memory from the WallpaperManager?

Answer (score 1):

You can do bitmap.recycle(). It frees the object associated with the bitmap and clears the reference to pixel data thereby allowing it to be grabage collected.

Comment: Yeah I'm doing that. Forgot to mention. Still the momory is not cleared.

Comment: you can also use third party libraries like Picasso(https://github.com/square/picasso) and Universal Image Loader(https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for loading images efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It will immediately frees the memory

```
bitmap.recycle();
bitmap = null;
```

Comment: Thanks but it won't actually. I tried that and it didn't help. The problem I think is with `WallpapaperManager.getDrawable()`.